# Business object and linq2SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

What is the optimal way to write the code which interacts with DB using linq2SQL? I need to add some business logic to the entities. So I guess there are two ways:

1. Write some wrapper class. The
   main minus is that many fields are
   the same, so i don't feel it as DRY
   style.
2. Add business logic methods
   to linq2sql entities(these classes
   are partial) directly
3. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the biggest benefit of them being generated as partial classes, is that you can extend functionality without the risk of it being stomped by code generation tools (i.e. if the DB schema changes)

Answer (score 1):

I normally keep my LINQ to SQL domain objects clean from any business logic. I write a separate business layer that contains the business logic. Of course you can mix this and add it to a partial class in your LINQ to SQL objects, as Rowland suggests.